# More SE sites added to close as off-topic list?

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

When one votes to close a question for being off-topic, one of the possible choices is that it "belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network", but the only site to choose from in the next screen is meta.scicomp.stackexchange.com. I think, at the very least, StackOverflow ought to be a possibility, and I suspect with a little data mining, some moderators could find the top 5 or so sites that we have migrated questions to in the past.

Edited to add: I'm talking about off-topic close reasons here not the explicit migration options. I gather from a maybe now deleted answer that the migration list is not to be messed with!

Comment: +1, from looking at http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/away, I'd say Math, DSP and Stats would be strong contenders as well.

Answer (score 6):

[**Edit**: Removed a previous answer about how SE doesn't want to set migration paths to and from beta sites, which isn't what this question is about.]

I think adding more custom off-topic close reasons would be a good idea, as the automatic comments are a much clearer (and easier to use) indication about the scope of this site than "see the help center". I would propose to at least add Math in addition to StackOverflow. For the comment, we could just copy the items from https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic:

- Questions on **programming** not requiring computational science expertise to understand or answer should be asked on http://stackoverflow.com.
- Questions about **mathematics** oriented towards proofs and analytical calculation not of a numerical or computational character should be asked on http://math.stackexchange.com.
- Questions about **physical theories** or closed form solutions rather than computational methods should be asked on http://physics.stackexchange.com.
- Questions primarily about data collection, data mining, probability theory, and **statistics**, should be asked on http://stats.stackexchange.com.

(I would prefer *not* to have a custom "ask on mathematica.se" -- which is another frequent target -- reason and instead use the standard "questions about specific software" reason.)

Comment: I don't understand your response, Christian. I'm not a mod or community manager, and *I* do see a list of options. I just has one option. Also, this isn't about migration to SciComp.SE, but about migration *from* it, which, frankly, happens all the time.

Comment: OK, I see, but can't we increase the options somewhere? I don't care where!

Answer (score 2):

Moderators have the option to migrate to a specific SE site.  I'm not sure if regular users with sufficient reputation points can do this as well. I get the feeling that migrating to "meta" is the only choice because the community should discuss (not just poll) the most appropriate site. Certainly, one can vote to close "for some other reason" and recommend a site for migration.

Comment: Yes, I do that all the time, but there's a convenient selector for the CS SE that makes a comment with the link and everything. I just want some more options in that selector!